# resize uploaded images file php

Tags: php, image, resize

i want to resize the images that is being uploaded by user to our server. i want it to be 200x200 px. for the moment, here is the code that i am working with. it uploads fine, but it does not resize the image to 200x200. or is there a way to shrink the file size?

```
// make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

// make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.form.php';

// make a note of the location of the success page
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self .     'upload.success.php';

// name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
$fieldname = 'file';


// Now let's deal with the upload

// possible PHP upload errors
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
            2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
            3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
            4 => 'no file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
isset($_POST['submit'])
or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

// check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

// validation... since this is an image upload script we 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
// not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one
//$now = time();

while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$fb_id.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]    ['name']))
{
//$now++;
}

// now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);
```

Comment: So you want us to write code for you?

Comment: the code that i give is working for upload only. how can i enhance it by adding a resizing feature? sorry, i am new to php

Comment: so you're new and want us to do your work for you. Say, I'm new in building houses - can you build one for me?

Answer (score 0):

Never shrink the file, it will cause unnecessary damage to the picture. Rather try to recreate the image with new scaled dimensions using image functions for instance [gd image functons](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). It provides everything that you will need to recreate and resize it. Also, you can use Imagick Library too, it has much more advanced functions to play around with.